# Composer - It is downloading packages but not installing

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install one of my on going work (github-repository) into my server. I successfully downloaded my work into my server using Git. This work is a laravel based work.

After I did basic composer configurations, I tried to execute the command

```
composer install -vvv
```

It seems that, it downloading and cacheing packages but not installing them. After downloading and cacheing, the `process get KILLED`. I cant trace what is the exact problem here ?

Is anyone face this issue before ? If anyone know why composer behave like this,then please let me know.

Comment: It might be because you don't hace enough RAM, I face the same issue in Digital Ocean dropplet and that was the problem

Comment: if that is the case, try running it with ```composer install -vvv --profile``` . The profile option displays timing and memory usage information.